# JavaScript appendChild() input to form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an `<input>` in `<form>` after page loads (`<body onload="random()>"`), but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

This is the script it self:

```
function random()
{
    var points = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", "points");
    input.setAttribute("value", points.toString());
    document.getElementById("redeem_form").appendChild(input);
}
```

This is form:

```
<form action="/redeem" method="POST" id="redeem_form">
     <label for="user_email">Enter your email: </label>
     <input type="email" id="user_email" name="email" required>
     <input type="submit" value="Redeem">
</form>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in your browser console

Comment: no, there is no error in console

Comment: The input element may not be visible because it is a hidden input... you need to inspect the dom structure to see whether it exists

Comment: remove the line `input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");` and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually creating a hidden input field. So, there is no error just an invisible field.

Try changing:

```
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
```

To:

```
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
```

Comment: there is no type visible

Comment: yes, I see it now. Now I see what was wrong: I tried to see added `<input>` in source code, not in inspector

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `input` added is actually `hidden`:

```
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
```

Please replace it with the;

```
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
```